# How can I store Strings from a Loop in an array and display them?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

So the basic concept of what I want to do is Loop through these Methods of User defined dates (year, month, day). Each date will be converted to a string which will be stored in an array. The array's size is determined by the user. The size of the array and amount of times the loop runs will be equal to each other of course. With my code currently, the loop stops and returns the string of the first date. How can I just store the value without printing it yet, and allow the loop to continue?

```
public class Assign4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    //Refer to Ledger Class
    Ledger InfoLedger = new Ledger();

    //Use Ledger Methods
    InfoLedger.UserArraySize(args);
    InfoLedger.LoopInvoice(args);

}
```

> Next Class, User Defines array size here

```
public class Ledger {

//Refer to Invoice Class
Invoice Info = new Invoice();

//Ledger Amount
public static int LedgerAmount;

//Create Ledger Array
public static String[] LedgerArray = new String[LedgerAmount];

//Create new array
public void UserArraySize(String[] args ) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of monthly invoices: ");
    LedgerAmount = keyboard.nextInt();
}

public void LoopInvoice(String[] args ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < LedgerAmount; i++) {
        Info.OurDateYear(args);
        Info.OurDateMonth(args);
        Info.OurDateDay(args);
        LedgerArray[i] = Info.DateString(args);
    }
  }
}
```

> This class just calls to OurDate, more use of it later on

```
public class Invoice {

//Refer to OurDate Class
OurDate Date = new OurDate();

//Todays Year
public void OurDateYear(String[] args ) {
    Date.setYearFromUser(args);
}

//Todays Month
public void OurDateMonth(String[] args ) {
    Date.setMonthFromUser(args);
}

//Todays Day
public void OurDateDay(String[] args ) {
    Date.setDayFromUser(args);
}

//Display the dates
public String DateString(String[] args ) {
    return Date.toString();
}
}
```

> This classes contains the user's methods and toString method

```
public class OurDate {
//Date variables and user requests
//integers for the month day and year of both set of inputs are set to defaults
public static Integer TodaysMonth = 1;
public static Integer TodaysDay = 1;
public static Integer TodaysYear = 1990;

//TodaysYear
//Prompt for the user to enter Todays Year
public void setYearFromUser(String[] args ) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Today's year (1900 to 2015): ");
    TodaysYear = keyboard.nextInt();

    //Error Checking to check that the Year entered is within the range of 1900 to 2015
    try{
        if(TodaysYear > 1899 && TodaysYear < 2016){
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid choice! Please enter a valid Year");
            setYearFromUser(args);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Invalid choice! Please enter a valid Year");
        setYearFromUser(args);
    }
}

//TodaysMonth
//Prompt for the user to enter Todays Month
public void setMonthFromUser(String[] args ) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Today's month(from 1 to 12): ");
    TodaysMonth = keyboard.nextInt();

    //Error Checking to check that the Month entered is within the range of 1 to 12
    try{
        if(TodaysMonth > 0 && TodaysMonth < 13){
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid choice! Please enter a valid Month");
            setMonthFromUser(args);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Invalid choice! Please enter a valid Month");
        setMonthFromUser(args);
    }
}

//TodaysDay
//Prompt for the user to enter Todays Day
public void setDayFromUser(String[] args ) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Today's day (1 to 30): ");
    TodaysDay = keyboard.nextInt();

    //Error Checking to check that the Day entered is within the range of 1 to 30
    try{
        if(TodaysDay > 0 && TodaysDay < 31){
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid choice! Please enter a valid Day");
            setDayFromUser(args);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Invalid choice! Please enter a valid Day");
        setDayFromUser(args);
    }
}

//Todays Date ToString
public String ToString(String[] args ) {
    return TodaysDay + "/" + TodaysMonth + "/" + TodaysYear;
}
}
```

Comment: FYI: Variables and fields should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Why do you keep passing on the String[] args? (genuine question)

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with those try-catch blocks. Did you intend to surround the `keyboard.nextInt()` as well? That would make more sense. You should also use camel case for (non-final) variables and methods. Random capitalization is making it a bit difficult to tell what is going on. I don't actually see where in your code you are telling it to print anything either. Could you provide a sample input/output?

Comment: Why are the `OurDate` fields `Integer`? Should be `int`.

Comment: @Andreas int fields were giving me issues so i went with Integer and it solved any Syntax errors there were.

Comment: @Monkeygrinder the Try and Catch statements are just to set a range, i know there's any easier way to do it, but its old code from past projects so i kept it as is

Comment: @Monkeygrinder As of now, there is not printing of the array yet, I'm trying to the loop to work first. Right now, I run the program, and it stop after the first 3 inputs of the Year, Month, and Day, displaying the returning string, ending the loop for some reason

Comment: @RyanStLouis It doesn't just stop, now does it? It ends with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception because `LedgerArray` is an array of length `0`, so `LedgerArray[i] = Info.DateString(args)` throws that exception.

Comment: @Andreas This is true. The array is initialized before a value is even input for `LedgerAmount`. Nice catch. I assumed from question was looking for a logic error as opposed to something that would throw an exception.
@RyanStLouis you have to initialize the array (or at least reinitialize, so to speak) after `ledgerAmount = keyboard.nextInt();`

Comment: Works like a charm! Much appreciated, thank you to the both of you.